# Hide ImageView when Softkeyboard is shown

Tags: android, show-hide, android-softkeyboard

I have a register activity with the logo and many EditTexts, the problem is that when I tried to fill the editTexts, the softkeyboard is shown and it hides the most part of the Edittexts, I tried with: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` but it doesn't work, I think, hidding the logo would be the solution, is there anyway to hide some ImageView when the keyboard is shown and show it again when the keyboard's hide?

These are the reference images:

This is the activity initially

[image: all EditTexts]

And this is how it looks with the keyboard

[image: KeyboarShown]

Comment: You can instead use a ScrollView, so put all you layout inside a ScrollView and when the key-board pops up the screen shrinks as it did earlier, but now you will be able to scroll through all the EditText's. Also, here is a link for what you had asked for. http://www.coderanch.com/t/624086/Android/Mobile/detect-virtual-keyboard-popped-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question (hiding image when keyboard pops up), use the following piece of code to hide/unhide the image.

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        image_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        image_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
   }
});
```

You can add this code on all the edittexts. But the best way to handle your situation would be to add all your content into a `ScrollView` so that when you use `adjustResize` it will automatically scroll up your views and the user can scroll to whichever fields he wants to go and he can also see the image.

Comment: Yes. Users do not expected parts of the UI to be hidden at random when they're trying to type. A `ScrollView` is definitely the best option here (and it will give your app better compatibility in general; screens can get pretty small!)

Comment: They are already in a scrollview, but the logo was out the scrollview, guess that I should put the logo inside the scrollview.

Comment: @El_Mochiq Adding all the views(including the logo) in the ScrollView would be best, since from your screenshots it seems that you have a big list of EditTexts.